# Is running MySQL on a separate server on LAN is any slower then running MySQL server locally?

Tags: mysql

I wonder if there is any significant speed difference because of network latency when:

- running Apache + PHP against a MySQL server that runs locally
- running Apache + PHP against a MySQL server that resides in the same LAN.

Specifically speaking, I plan to separate database from application server in Amazon's EC2 environment, and I am not sure if this will affect the speed of connections to database. The application is Revive Adserver (about 20 concurrent active mysql connections)

Comment: It depends on the LAN and the DB load.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the LAN is EC2 environment. The application is Revive Adserver, that has at average 20 active concurrent mysql connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test it in your specific case. If everything else is the same, connecting over the LAN will likely be slower, but if you can avoid a bottleneck by offloading the DB or even have an optimized server for the DB workload (e.g. with more RAM and/or faster disks), it might be much faster in practice.

Comment: So, presuming the database is not the bottleneck right now, it will definitely be slower? Any estimation how significant will it be: 10 times, or 50 percent?

Comment: Measure it in your use case. I can't and won't give you a number.